# Taking the summation in XArray over different dates

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I have two Xarray DataArrays as follows:

A reference image

```
print(reference)
<xarray.DataArray 'A' (time: 1, y: 38507, x: 33959)>
dask.array<shape=(1, 38507, 33959), dtype=float32, chunksize=(1, 1000, 1000)>
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2019-08-21
Dimensions without coordinates: y, x
```

And a dataset of a stack of images

```
print(dataset)
<xarray.DataArray 'A' (time: 2, y: 38507, x: 33959)>
dask.array<shape=(2, 38507, 33959), dtype=float32, chunksize=(1, 1000, 1000)>
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2019-09-02 2019-09-04
Dimensions without coordinates: y, x
```

I'd am trying to subtract the `reference` image from each image in the `dataset` but this always leaves me with a DataArray where the time dimension is 0. I understand that this is because the timestamps do not match, but I am not sure how to do this computation without having to worry about time stamps.

I have tried

```
result = dataset.data - reference.data
result = result.compute()
```

But the entire result is just full of NaNs then, while the datasets are not.

What is the correct way to perform this operation using XArray and Dask?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of subtracting a reference image from a stack of images, it probably makes the most sense to [`squeeze`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.squeeze.html#xarray.Dataset.squeeze) out the time dimension of the reference image, and then do the subtraction.  This will avoid the issue of alignment based on the time coordinates:

```py
result = dataset - reference.squeeze()
```